# How to add code-block formatting without editing anything else?

Tags: discussion

Consider [this post](https://superuser.com/posts/436318/revisions). In the original form, it had a block of program output which was not formatted as a code block. I tried to fix this, but SU doesn't accept edits with less than 6 non-whitespace characters modified.

To overcome this limit, I changed a word to one of its synonyms, but this seems pretty hackish. What is the recommended way to solve such problems?

Comment: you could've edited the title.

Comment: Hmm… didn't think about that. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While we welcome all edits, you should try to edit a question in a more comprehensive manner.

For instance, the question above, you could've edited the title to a more meaningful one.

Here's a cursory glance of what you should look at while editing any post:

- Does the title make sense? Will someone find the question if the person's searching for the same answer?
- Can the post body be corrected? Are all words capitalized correctly? Is the sentence comprehensible? Does it make sense?
- Is there something that's left out of body? For example, are there any extra info that can be moved from comments to the main post?
- Is it tagged correctly? Are there any [meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)? If so get rid of them. Add some meaningful tags.

In the rare occasion that you *absolutely* do not have anything to add - I'd suggest you drop by our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) and ask for assistance.. most users in chat are likely to have edit privileges.